# Special Fibonacci sequence

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Let $\{F_n\}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ be the sequence of Fibonacci numbers such that $F_1=1$, $F_2=1$ and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ $\forall n\geq2$.

Define a new sequence $\{S_n\}$ such that $S_n=F_n+1$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now the question is: For every prime $p$, does there exist an $N\in  \mathbb{N}$, such that $p|S_N$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. The answer is yes. Show that for any prime $p\not=5$, 
$$p\;\mbox{divides}\;S_{p^2-3}=F_{p^2-3}+1.$$
See for example Jack D'Aurizio's answer here:[Fibonacci Sequence problem. Prove that there are infinitely many prime numbers such that $p$ divides $F_{p-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985541/fibonacci-sequence-problem-prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-s/1985568#1985568)

Answer (score 0):

Well $S_{-2}=0$, but $-2\notin\Bbb N$. Never mind!

Comment: what do you mean by $S_-2$ ???

$-2$ is not a natural number

actually, i believe i got  what you wanted to say but explain further

Comment: I said that $-2$ wasn't a natural number, didn't I? The Fibonacci sequence does extend naturally to negative arguments, doesn't it?

Comment: Hmm, and the Fibonacci series is periodic (mod $n$) for any $n$ - also the naturally extended Fibonacci series.  I think these two observations together solve the question.

Comment: yes..........true